# Шифровать строку

Tags: php, codeigniter

День добрый!

Мне нужно зашифровать url адрес так, чтобы его мог понимать только php, а человек не смог расшифровать, только с ключом, имею под рукой CodeIgniter

```
$ch = curl_init("http://music.art/api/key");
```

Вот тот URL в методе нужно бы зашифровать, есть такая возможность?

Comment: в смысле сделать опцию нечитабельной ? ну зашифруй ее rsa каким-нибудь и в base64 закодируй. аа, я понял кажется, ты хочешь в исходнике ее скрыть, обфускаторы в помошь, всякие ioncube тд

Comment: После обфускаторов у меня целостность скрипта нарушается, и не работает многое.

Comment: ну а какова цель то скрытия строки ? может как-то по-другому решается этот вопрос ? (ну и шифруйте не весь проект а скажем модель или либу которая вызывает этот curl с этой строкой) в любом случае, всегда можно сниффером перехватить строку, если https конечно придется помучаться немного, libcurl/libssl там подменить и тд... но достаточно простою